# How to parse JSON object in Java:

Tags: java, javascript, json, dojo

I am trying to parse to JSON object in java. I am posting json key value object using `dojo.xhrPost()` method as shown below:

```
dojo.xhrPost({
url: /esturl/,
handleAs : "text",
content : {INST1 : {"0001" : "aa"},
            INST2 : {"0002" : "bb"},
            INST3 : {"0003" : "cc"}},
load : load(data),
error : error
});
```

Now I am reading this post data from request context:

```
Map<String, String[]> paramMap = requestContext.getParameterMap();
```

when I am printing this in loop:

```
Iterator it = paramMap.entrySet().iterator();
while(it.hasnext()){
 Map.entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
 System.out.println(pairs.getKey());
 System.out.println(pairs.getkValue());

}
```

this returns me :

```
INST1
[Ljava.lang.String;@1b4cef
INST2
[Ljava.lang.String;@5801d
```

like wise, but I should be getting values like

`INST1 : {"0001" : "aa"}, INST2 : {"0002" : "bb"}, INST3 : {"0003" : "cc"}},` any guidance would be highly appreciated.

**Update**

When I try to get value of one parameter using

```
String[] X = requestContext.getParameters{"INST1"};

if (X != null){
   System.out.println(X.length);
   System.out.println(X[0]);
   System.out.println(X[0].length);
}
```

then am getting :

```
1
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

**Q** Now how can I get actual values of Object like `INST1 : {"0001" : "aa"}` instead of [object Object] ?

Comment: [Ljava.lang.String;@1b4cef - The 'L' here means that its an array. SO may be be varialbe INST1 is taking the values as array of strings

Comment: @Gaurav: Yes, that is true but how can I read it ? I want to further process it but at this point of time am not able to read it and so cannot do further processing with it, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as given in the dojo documentation [here](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.2/dojo.xhrPost) the object which you set up will be read as name1=value1. So may be in your case the variables are being passed like INST1=0001,INST1=aa.

You can try to make the syntax of 'content' on these lines - `INST1 : '{"0001" : "aa"}'` or
`INST1 : "{\"0001\" : \"aa\"}"` so that INST1 has 1 unambiguous value

Comment: Yes, now am able to get values as expected, I never thought that there would be such an issue, thanks Gaurav for your guidance.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this modified [JSONObject class](http://www.json.org/java/org/json/JSONObject.java), pass the raw JSON code through the constructor or create (new object and assign JSON content later..) and use built-in *get* methods. view full javadoc [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).